# php cookie change to NULL when jump to another page

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, cookies

In my controller/Welcome.php I include a login function. Rhis is not the entire code. I include just key parts of the code so that you can read it clearer. I set the default `login_status`as `false`. When user has correct username and password, the `login_status`is set as `true`.
However, in my project/Home.php, I try retrieve the cookie "login_status". but the cookie becomes `NULL`.
The key parts of the code are as follows:

controller/Welcome.php public function login()

```
        $this->input->set_cookie('login_status',FALSE,time()+3600);//delete or not

        if($this->input->cookie('login_status')==FALSE){    

            //The following code means login password match the username
            elseif($infomatch){

                if($remember == 1){
                    $this->input->set_cookie('username',$username,time()+3600);
                    $this->input->set_cookie('password',$password,time()+3600);
                    $this->input->set_cookie('remember',$remember,time()+3600);
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->input->set_cookie('username',"",time()-3600);
                    $this->input->set_cookie('password',"",time()-3600);
                    $this->input->set_cookie('remember',"",time()-3600);
                }
                $this->input->set_cookie('login_status',TRUE,time()+3600);//hihihihihi
                redirect('home');

            }

    }
```

controller/Home.php

```
if($this->input->cookie('login_status')==FALSE){
            header("location: Welcome/login");
        } else{


            $this->session->set_userdata('login_status',TRUE);

            $this->load->database();
            $this->load->model('scheduler_model');
            $this->load->view('header.php');

            $data['username'] = $this->session->userdata('username');

            $data["getnames"]=$this->scheduler_model->get_users();
            $this->load->view('home/homepage',$data);

            $data["getassignments"]=$this->scheduler_model->get_assignment();
            $data["getselectedcourses"]=$this->scheduler_model->get_select_course();
            $this->load->view('home/assignments',$data);  
        }
```

Comment: Never store passwords in cookies. Use server side sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are plain text.You can not store boolean values in cookies. What you can do is storing a string that represent the boolean value. Ex: `1 for true` and `0 for false`

```
$this->input->set_cookie('login_status','0',3600); //set it to '1' in the log in process
//also notice: expiration is how long it should remain in seconds
```

To check

```
if($this->input->cookie('login_status')== '0'){
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. However, the problem is still there that when I go to the profile page, the login_status cookie becomes NULL.

Comment: Updated: remove the `time()`